# Is there a way to strip an expression of all functions of a variable in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

Say I have an equation:

```
 eq = sym.Eq(5*x**2 + 2*x + 5*y + f_1(y) + f_2(x), 0)
```

Is there a way in Sympy to strip the function of x portion and the function of y portion from the above expression?

My goal is something like:

```
sym.strip(eq, x)
>>>5*x**2 + 2*x + f_2(x)
sym.strip(eq, y)
>>>5*y + f_1(y)
```

Comment: I guess something like `eq.replace(lambda a: a.has(x), lambda a: 0)` but that works top-down.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this will work with the equation you defined, but this seemed to work for me for polynomials. Try this or an adaptation of it.

```
def strip_sym(expr, sym):
    newExpr = 0
    for term in expr.args:
        newTerm = term if sym in term.free_symbols else 0
        newExpr = newExpr + newTerm
    return newExpr
```